# How to get current user logged in for EnvironmentUserName instead of "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" when web app is deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, impersonation, serilog-aspnetcore

I have a basic CRUD web app that saves user form input to a database. The the current user id is saved along with the form input without any issues both locally and on IIS. However, when I save `EnvironmentUserName` in logs via Serilog after publishing the website to IIS, the `EnvironmentUserName` is always saved as "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool." When I run the web app locally, it captures my user id as expected.

I tried writing a custom enricher to use the same logic of capturing the user id as I do when I retrieve the user id to save with the form input in the database, however the results remain the same as `EnvironmentUserName`.

I've been reading up on [impersonation in ASP NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation) but did not find an example where I can apply it to logging in general.

**How do I include the current logged in user's id in my log when the web app is run from IIS without getting "IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool" via Serilog?**

Custom enricher:

```
public class CurrentUserEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    static readonly string _currentUser;

    /// <summary>
    /// static constructor to load the environment variable
    /// </summary>
    static CurrentUserEnricher()
    {
        _currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToUpper();
    }

    public void Enrich(
        LogEvent logEvent,
        ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var enrichProperty = propertyFactory
            .CreateProperty(
                "CurrentUser",
                _currentUser);

        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(enrichProperty);
    }
}
```

Here's my appSettings.config. Note that I'm saving "CurrentUser" as "EnvironmentUserName" after writing my custom enricher.

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DuckDatabase": "data source=*****;initial catalog=*****;integrated security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True",
    "GooseDatabase": "data source=*****;initial catalog=*****;integrated security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "CustomSerilogEnrichers" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "ConsultsDatabase",
          "sinkOptionsSection": {
            "tableName": "Logs",
            "schemaName": "dbo",
            "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
            "batchPostingLimit": 1000,
            "period": "0.00:00:30"
          },
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "EnvironmentUserName",
                "PropertyName": "CurrentUser",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "MachineName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "Application",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 50
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithMachineName", "WithCurrentUser" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Medical Consults"
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs, where I setup Serilog:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS;
using Serilog;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System;

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
        .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting Medical Consults web application");

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Host.UseSerilog();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddNegotiate();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
       .AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("AllowedRoles")));

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowedRoles",
            policy => policy.RequireRole("*****"));
    });

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Project specs:

- Project type: ASP.Net Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)
- .Net framework: 7.0
- Target OS: Windows

Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate v.7.0.10
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore v.7.0.10
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v.7.0.10
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design v.7.0.10
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v.7.0.10
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design v.7.0.9
- Serilog.AspNetCore v.7.0.0
- Serilog.Enrichers.Environment v.2.2.0
- Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer v.6.3.0

Comment: Keep in mind web apps are different desktop apps, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Read `Controller.User` and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

I only have two examples of getting the current logged in user. I am sure there are other ways some being framework dependent.

Blazor Server: Using the AuthenticationStateProvider class.

```
    AuthenticationState authState = await _authState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    ClaimsPrincipal? user = authState.User;
    if(user == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(user.Identity == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach(var role in roles)
    {
        if(user.IsInRole(role))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Using a Controller:

```
var sv = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
var user = (sv == null) ? "No IIS?" : sv["LOGON_USER"];
```

These might not be exactly what you are looking for, and you may want to add/remove more types of checks, but both of these do produce the currently logged in user through IIS.